# extract python string into variables

Tags: python, string

In python, I have defined this sql string:

```
sqlstring=''
for i in range(1001):
    sqlstring+="dz"+str(i)+"\n"
```

I want to extract variables from this string.

so sql string contains :

```
dz0
dz1 
dz2 
dz3
dz4...
```

I want to have `dz1` as one variable, how can i do that?

Comment: You mean you want to dynamically create variables called `dz1`, `dz2`...?

Comment: Please give us more details, what 's your expected output?

Comment: BTW, the first line of that should be `dz0`, not `dz1`. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @SiHa: I want to extract variables from this sql string , I dont want to create dynamic variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sqlstring='dz1 dz2 dz3 dz4 dz5'
datalist=[]
newsqlstring=sqlstring.split()
for each in newsqlstring:
    datalist+=[each]
print datalist
```

or if you want to create these use a list instead of string

```
sqlstring=[]
for i in range(1001):
    sqlstring+=["dz"+str(i)+"\n"]
```

Comment: if this solve your query then accept the answer, so that it can help other readers in future

Comment: You have no idea what the question really means. Why are you answering it?

Comment: Can you please explain to the numerous people, including me, who did not understand the question please?

Answer (score 0):

How about that you store those in a `list` and access them by `index`:

```
>>>sqllist = ['dz{}'.format(i) for i in range(1001)]
>>>sqllist[0]
dz0
>>>sqlist[1]
dz1
```

If you have 1000 variables that have those names you can access them with:

```
>>>eval(sqllist[0])
'something stored in dz0'
```